# How to call an async method thousand of times in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, async-await, parallel.foreach

I want to call an async method for about 1000 time in parallel.

I have an datatable that has about 10000 rows. I want to compare two rows of it and if some conditions are true then call an async method. Overall this method(GetApiData()) maybe called for about 1000 times. I read a few articles and write some code. My simplified code is:

```
public static HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000 };

private Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    httpClientHandler.Proxy = null;
    httpClientHandler.UseProxy = false;
    await DoWork();
}

public async Task DoWork()
{
    var allTasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if(Some condition)
        allTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetApiData()));            
    }
    Task waitAll = Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
    await waitAll;
}

public async Task GetApiData()
{
    var Result= await (await Client.GetAsync("Some Url")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //do some cpu bound(but not too heavy, like search in a datatable that have 20 rows) work on Result.
}
```

This code worked for me but I think it take too much time. I had some questions:
1- Is my code parallel. If not how can I do it. When I put break point to "Task waitAll = Task.WhenAll(allTasks);" line, it takes too time to reach this line and so I think my code isn't parallel(I know that tasks runs after created).
2- I need to write some data in datatable to improve my code but I know that datatable is not thread safe. Is there a simple way to convert datatable to thread safe data structure.
3-I think my code is I/O bound However, If I prepare a computer that have more core(like Server) for example 24 core and 48 thread, is this reduce my code time. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find it but i am pretty sure there is a hard limit on a single `HttpClient`. But as for parallelism your code seems correct. You launch all the queries and have the correct way of waiting for all to complete. a `Datatable` is a simple structure. Each row is a class with 1 property for each column. Create a thread-friendly collection with custom class. For testing you can use `object[]` to contain the values. Yes it's boxing/unboxing but for proof of concept it's enough. When ready make it a proper class and you will be good to go

Comment: @Franck, Thanks for your answer. What is your means of " there is a hard limit on a single HttpClient". Would you suggest to have several HttpClient? If I can divide my datatable(or thread-friendly collection) to several datatable and run each one in parallel mode, Is this case can reduce my code time.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but i think once you have like 25 query out, no other can go out until at least one got a response. Don't take that as a fact, i just know there was this kind of limit in the past and the solution was as easy as to have more HttpClient objects when i was doing many many queries.

Comment: @Franck Thanks, your hint about hard limit on a single HttpClient saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I Thanks @Franck for his hint:"I can't find it but i am pretty sure there is a hard limit on a single HttpClient", I divide my datatable to four(my system has 4 thread) separate datatable and then define four HttpClient instance, and use each HttpClient only for on datatable:

```
public static HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
private static HttpClient Client1 = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000 };`
private static HttpClient Client2 = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000 };`
private static HttpClient Client3 = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000 };`
private static HttpClient Client4 = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 10000000 };

private Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    httpClientHandler.Proxy = null;
    httpClientHandler.UseProxy = false;
    Task t1=Task.Run(()=>DoWork(dt1,Client1));
    Task t1=Task.Run(()=>DoWork(dt2,Client2));
    Task t1=Task.Run(()=>DoWork(dt3,Client3));
    Task t1=Task.Run(()=>DoWork(dt4,Client4));
    await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3,t4);
}

public async Task DoWork(DataTable dt,HttpClient Client)
{
    var allTasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if(Some condition)
        allTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetApiData(Client)));            
    }
    Task waitAll = Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
    await waitAll;
}

public async Task GetApiData(HttpClient Client)
{
    var Result= await (await Client.GetAsync("Some Url")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //do some cpu bound(but not too heavy, like search in a datatable that have 20 rows) work on Result.
}
```

Before that my code take about 450 seconds but now it take about 280 second. I'm surprising beacuse now I Think we must balance between reusing HttpClient and "hard limit on a single HttpClient". Thanks.